# Throwing Exception In SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, api, spring-boot, exception

So I'm trying to throw an exception for a GET request (more requests are coming but for now I'm working on GET). Before I created my error package and the classes in it, I got the usual java null pointer error. But, after I created them, I only got this

{}

in the postman when I put the incorrect ID. Here are my classes starting from exception package to the controller

RecordNotFoundException class

```
package com.yash.questionnaire.exception;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class RecordNotFoundException extends RuntimeException
{
    public RecordNotFoundException(String exception) {
        super(exception);
    }
}
```

ErrorResponse class

```
package com.yash.questionnaire.exception;

import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "error")
public class ErrorResponse
{
    public ErrorResponse(String message, List<String> details) {
        super();
        this.message = message;
        this.details = details;
    }

    //General error message about nature of error
    private String message;

    //Specific errors in API request processing
    private List<String> details;

    //Getter and setters
}
```

CustomExceptionHandler class

```
package com.yash.questionnaire.exception;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.ObjectError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked","rawtypes"})
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler
{
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
        details.add(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse("Server Error", details);
        return new ResponseEntity(error, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(RecordNotFoundException.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleUserNotFoundException(RecordNotFoundException ex, WebRequest request) {
        List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
        details.add(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse("Record Not Found", details);
        return new ResponseEntity(error, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
        for(ObjectError error : ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors()) {
            details.add(error.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse("Validation Failed", details);
        return new ResponseEntity(error, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

StudyController class

```
package com.yash.questionnaire.web;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.yash.questionnaire.exception.RecordNotFoundException;
import com.yash.questionnaire.model.Study;
import com.yash.questionnaire.repository.MapValidationError;
import com.yash.questionnaire.repository.StudyRepository;

import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiParam;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@Api(value= "DDR", description="This API provides the facility to create a new Study")
public class StudyController {

    @Autowired
    private StudyRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private MapValidationError mapValidationError;    //ToDo: to fetch Json post request

    @ApiOperation(value = "Read a study by study-name")
    @GetMapping("/studies/{studyType}")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> getByStudyType(@ApiParam(value = "Questionnaire StudyType will retrieve", required = true) @PathVariable("studyType") String studyType) {
        try {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(repository.getByStudyType(studyType), HttpStatus.OK);

        } catch (RecordNotFoundException ex) {
            throw new RecordNotFoundException("Invalid studyType : " + studyType);
        }
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to display the custom error I put in StudyController class instead of just {}

Comment: are you getting `404` error code? and can you try with only one parameter `handleUserNotFoundException(RecordNotFoundException ex)`

Comment: @Deadpool before i made the exception package, i got 500 error code with "java.lang.NullPointerException" in the message, after i made the package I just get {} and yes I tried your suggestion but its still giving me {}

Comment: You already have that methos right in the exception class, just remove the second argument @J.Doe

Comment: sorry i dont understand, which second argument are you talking about? the one in studycontroller?

Comment: change this `public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleUserNotFoundException(RecordNotFoundException ex, WebRequest request)` to this `public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleUserNotFoundException(RecordNotFoundException ex)` and try

Comment: @Deadpool still doesnt work

Comment: I can't debug your code, but i can guide you how to pull out from this, First find out which method in `CustomExceptionHandler` is getting executed when exception is thrown. that solves the problem

Comment: @Deadpool CustomExceptionHandler is using RecordNotFoundException class as an annotation and a parameter in the method handleRecordNotFoundException, but to answer your question, CustomExceptionHandler first executed in StudyController  inside the catch block (RecordNotFoundException)

Answer (score -1):

maybe you should remove @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) on the exception class.

Comment: This is more suitable for a comment then an answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
package com.vk.common;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class RecordNotFoundException extends Exception {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public RecordNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```